# Close zeros of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

If an analytic function $f(z)$ has two zeros which are close together, there is a zero of $f^\prime(z)$ which is nearby.  This is clear if $f(z)$ is a quadratic polynomial, and intuitive in general from the Hadamard product: $f(z)$ is a quadratic polynomial times a function which is nearly constant in the neighborhood of the zeros.

**How rigorous can we make this statement?**

Without loss of generality, we can translate so the origin is the midpoint of the two zeros, rotate so they are both real, and dilate so the zeros are $\pm1$, so $f(z)=(1-z^2)g(z)$, with (suppose) $g(z)\ne0$ on $|z|<1$.  Thus $\log(g(z))$ is well defined on the disk, and we can write $g(z)=\exp(h(z))$ with analytic $h(z)$.

Thus we seek $z$ (hopefully in $|z|<1$) satisfying $-2z+(1-z^2)h^\prime(z)=0$.

**Edit**:  Based on robjohn's comment, we need to quantify the heuristic above that the 'remainder' of the Hadamard product is roughly constant near the zeros.  Thus assume also that $g^\prime(0)$ is 'small', where the proposed solution below makes this precise.

Comment: The function $f(z)=e^{2\pi iz}-1$ is $0$ at each integer, yet $f'(z)=2\pi i\;e^{2\pi iz}$ is never $0$.

Comment: @robjohn:  Nicely done, and so much for folklore.  The problem is not the 'wlog' either, as one can take $\exp(2\pi iz/\epsilon)-1$ for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: You might be interested in Sendov's Conjecture: If $p(z)=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdots(z-z_n)$ is a polynomial where the zeros $z_k$ are in the closed unit disc, then each of the discs $D_n=\{w:|w-z_k|\le1\}$ contains a zero for $p'$.

Comment: Forgot to mention the constrain that $p$ in the above comment is of degree $\ge2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**  Here's a cleaner solution based on the assumption that $\log(g(z))$ is roughly constant near the zeros.

Write $\log(g(z))=h(z)=h(0)+h^\prime(0)z+h^{\prime\prime}(0)z^2/2+O(z^3)$, and
consider the series expansion of 
$$
-2z+(1-z^2)h^\prime(z).
$$
Up to terms which are $O(z^2)$, this is
$$
h^\prime(0)+\left(h^{\prime\prime}(0)-2\right)z.
$$
Thus neglecting the $O(z^2)$, the expression is $0$ for 
$$
z=\frac{h'(0)}{2-h''(0)}.
$$
This is in the unit disk for $h^\prime(0)$ sufficiently small, as long as $h^{\prime\prime}(0)$ is not too close to $2$.

**Question:**  What is the 'meaning' of the second derivative of $\log(g(z))$ at $0$ being near $2$?

Comment: The $2$ appears because of the normalization of the zeros to be $\pm 1$.  In general if the zeros are $\pm\lambda$, one sees $2/\lambda^2$.